# Kubuntu 16.04 network-manager failed to edit connection with crued log

Tags: networking, network-manager

Always I want to edit a network-connection(WiFi, VPN, eth etc.) I get a log-message something like

```
May 2 21:39:19 mylaptop NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1462217959.6967] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="850afb13-cf82-402c-af7a-80408324329a" name="myname1" result="fail" reason="connection.gateway-ping-timeout: can not set property: value "32497520" of type 'guint' is invalid or out of range for property 'gateway-ping-timeout' of type 'guint'"
```

which seems to be a false default value of a variable inside the network-manager? How to solve this problem? Is this a bug of the network-manager?

Additional information:

```
me@mylaptop:/etc/NetworkManager$ NetworkManager --version
1.1.93
```

After looking under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, I found all my connections. In every connection there is another `gateway-ping-timeout`, but I cannot edit this variable within the plasma network manager. So I think anywhere in the communication between the Plasma desktopapplication and the NetworkManager there is a fault.?!

Comment: It seems to be an already reported bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/networkmanager-qt/+bug/1569674?comments=all

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been reported to KDE and they have provided a patch to the networkmanager-qt package.  I am looking for people to test it.  If you can install one of the following packages (one is for amd64 and the second is i386)

https://launchpad.net/~clivejo/+archive/ubuntu/xenial/+files/libkf5networkmanagerqt6_5.18.0-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04~ppa1_amd64.deb

https://launchpad.net/~clivejo/+archive/ubuntu/xenial/+files/libkf5networkmanagerqt6-dbg_5.18.0-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04~ppa1_i386.deb

Please let me know if the patched package solves your problem.

Comment: i test /libkf5networkmanagerqt6_5.18.0-0ubuntu2~ubuntu16.04~ppa1_amd64.deb and it works for me - no error now

Comment: Has this been implemented yet The link above doesn't work I also updated that library on my pc and still no changes.  Im using vlan connections

Comment: hay Clivejo  I just played around some more and found an intrestig thing.  while editing the connectionn if i do not  specify the vlan interface name I do not get this error